# Xcode 6 editor: No longer able to sort the Methods drop down?

Tags: xcode, methods

On Xcode 5 and earlier, one could alphabetize the items in the Methods dropdown list (at the top of the editor) by holding down the control key and clicking on the dropdown (or maybe it was the cmd key, I don't remember). This was an extremely useful feature. I can't seem to do that with Xcode 6. Has it changed? I can't find anything anywhere about it.

Comment: File a bug at Apple: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks, I've now done that. I wasn't sure if it was a bug or if it had been removed or they had somehow changed it.